# Android- setDuration not Working? ObjectAnimator

Tags: android, animation

I'm trying to move an ImageView down using ObjectAnimator. The setDuration() method doesn't seem to impact the duration of the animation. I can't set this animation in the XML as I want to play this dynamically.

```
    ObjectAnimator an= ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(img, View.TRANSLATION_Y, 0, 100);
    an.setDuration(5000);
    an.start();
```

Sorta off topic here but say I want to play more than one of those ObjectAnimation after each other, Is there a way to do that? I've looked at the Animator set but I wasn't sure if it would move the actual object like an Object Animator, instead of just appearing as so as in the TranslateAnimation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For sequential animations, take a look at `AnimatorSet`.

Comment: Ok, I did the best I could.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe you are testing on Samsung device? In this case, under developer options there is the option **Animator duration scale** that is set to off by default. If you switch to the normal value you can see the animations.

Hope this help.

Comment: No, but I disabled the Animator Duration Scale. It works now, thanks for the help. Now is there a way for me to animate views that won't be impacted by the Animator Duration Scale?

Comment: So, basically if i did add animations using animator.setDuration to my app, and a person has disabled the animator duration scale, all he will see, are things going by very fast?

Answer (score 0):

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

```
    final View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.loading_popup, null,false);
    popup = new PopupWindow(popupView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, true);
    popup.setContentView(popupView);
    popup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    ImageView loadingPlane=(ImageView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.loading_plane);

    RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.5f);
    // Step 2:  Set the Animation properties
    anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    //anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);

    anim.setRepeatCount(-1);
    anim.setDuration(1500);
    loadingPlane.startAnimation(anim);

    findViewById(R.id.flyinstyle).post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            popup.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.flyinstyle), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        }
    });
```